# Trivial Question : generating function

Tags: generating-functions

How does $ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 = \frac {1-x^5}{1-x} $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $\dfrac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots$, then you can use this fact after breaking up the fraction:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-x^5}{1-x} &= \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{x^5}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-x} - x^5\frac{1}{1-x} \\
&= (1 + x + x^2 + \ldots) - x^5(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots) \\
& = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4
\end{align}
$$

This is effectively the reverse direction of some of the other answers.

Comment: How do we convert a power series to a polynomial as in this case from $ 1+x+x^2+... to\; 1 + x+x^2+x^3+x^4 ? $ i.e. How do we know to multiply by $ (1-x^5) $ ?

Comment: Starting from $S = 1+x+x^2+\ldots$, if you want to transform it into $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$, then look at what needs to be removed, which is $x^5+x^6+x^7+\ldots$; let's call this series $T$. So far, we have $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 = S-T$. Next it's a matter of simplifying $T$: taking out the common factor, $x^5$, we have $$T = x^5(1+x+x^2+\ldots) = x^5S.$$
Therefore $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 = S - x^5S = (1-x^5)S$.

Answer (score 3):

$(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)(1-x)=(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4) - (x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4+x^5) = 1-x^5$

Answer (score 3):

Think of $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ as a geometric series with common ratio $x$. The sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric series is given by $$S_n = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$where $a$ is the first term and $r$ the common ratio. Here $a = 1$, $r = x$, $n = 5$ so we get $$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $$\displaystyle S = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4\tag1$$

Now Multiply both side by $x\;,$

We Get $$x\cdot S = x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5\tag2$$

Now $(1)-(2)\;,$ We Get $$\displaystyle (1-x)\cdot S = 1-x^5\Rightarrow S = \frac{1-x^5}{1-x}$$

Comment: Is it **your** solution ? I think that this was already solved by Pythagoras.

Comment: @lapin: juantheron's answer does _not_ involve infinite series.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the dots, because they made the sums appear as infinite series.

Comment: deleted the comment after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

All this comes from the high school identity:
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$
and setting $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S= 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 \quad I$

*multiplying both sides by x*

$xS=x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4+x^5 \quad II$

*Subtracting II by I*

$S(1-x)=1-x^5$

*Dividing the equation by $(1-x)$*

$S=\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}$